# Hive SQL: How to identify duplicates across groups

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I'm hoping to find duplicates across grouped IDs based on item, such as the following:

Hoping to derive the Dup variable based on duplicates of Item by ID groups.In other words, if the same item is found in another ID then Dup is 'yes'. If the Item only repeats within the same ID, then Dup is 'no'.

Table1:

```sql
+----+--------+-----+
| ID |  Item  | Dup |
+----+--------+-----+
| a  | apple  | yes |
| a  | apple  | yes |
| b  | apple  | yes |
| c  | orange | no  |
| c  | orange | no  |
| d  | pear   | yes |
| f  | pear   | yes |
| e  | mango  | no  |
+----+--------+-----+
```

I'm not sure if to start off by de-duplicating the dataset by ID and Item will make it easier.

Finalized dataset for summary (de-duped) :

Table2

```sql
+----+--------+-----+
| ID |  Item  | Dup |
+----+--------+-----+
| a  | apple  | yes |
| b  | apple  | yes |
| c  | orange | no  |
| d  | pear   | yes |
| f  | pear   | yes |
| e  | mango  | no  |
+----+--------+-----+
```

How should I construct a hive query to detect the duplicates?
Any help will be appreciative!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . if I understand correctly, you can use aggregation and a window function:

```
select id, item,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by item) > 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end) as dups
from t
group by id, item;
```

Comment: Adding group by will give me Table 2 right? If I do not use group by, I will get Table 1 ?

Comment: If I partition by id, ID c will generate 'yes' for dup?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I edited the question could you review? Hope it is more clear now. I'm not sure just partition by ID is enough, my main goal is find out if  the same Item has re-appeared in other ID.

Comment: @lydia . . . I think you want `partition by item`.